# Nested XML processing with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document with following structure:

- root element DataModel can have children Node, Integer and String
- Node element can have children Node, Integer and String as well

E.g.:

```
<DataModel>
  <String name="a">aaa</String>
  <Integer name="b">bbb</Integer>
  <Node name="n1">
   <String name="k">kkk</String>
    <Integer name="l">lll</Integer>
    <Node name="n2">
      <String name="x">xxx</String>
    </Node>
  </Node>
</DataModel>
```

I'd like to process this XML, flattening the output, but bringing the hierarchical structure in the naming, like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>n1.k</td>
    <td>kkk</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>n1.l</td>
    <td>lll</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>n1.n2.x</td>
    <td>xxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="DataModel">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>


            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::Node">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, '.')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to XML:

```
<DataModel>
    <String name="a">aaa</String>
    <Integer name="b">bbb</Integer>
    <Node name="n1">
        <String name="k">kkk</String>
        <Integer name="l">lll</Integer>
        <Node name="n2">
            <String name="x">xxx</String>
        </Node>
    </Node>
</DataModel>
```

Will produce desired output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>n1.k</td>
        <td>kkk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>n1.l</td>
        <td>lll</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>n1.n2.x</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: The last `<tr>` node is wrong; the first `<td>` within it should have the content `n1.n2.x`.

Answer (score 0):

This template supports any depth of nesting, thanks to **for-each** with **ancestor**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="DataModel">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>


            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="String|Integer">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::Node">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, '.')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so the result is exactly as required, including the last row:

```
...
  <tr>
    <td>n1.n2.x</td>
    <td>xxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```